# Laravel CRON Artisan error

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

When I call a artisan command by cron i get error:

```
/usr/local/php7.0/bin/php: /usr/local/adds/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4)
/usr/local/php7.0/bin/php: /usr/local/adds/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4)
/usr/local/php7.0/bin/php: /usr/local/adds/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4)


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]       
  Class 'Symfony\Component\Process\ExecutableFinder' not found
```

My cron command is:

/usr/local/php7.0/bin/php /home/path_to_project/artisan email:send

What's wrong? When I call this command by php 5.6 it's the same.

Comment: Does it work outside of cron? Did you install all [server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#server-requirements)?

Comment: create a batch file that will lead to your cron command to the cron core file ..

Comment: Try to run `composer dump-autoload` command in your root project directory to see if that solves your problem or not.